# How to upgrade namespace all together?

Tags: qt, namespaces, qml, qt-creator

I wanna update namespaces of the old project all together.

Currently I use replace tool (Menu Edit => Replace).

For Example I replace

```
import QtQuick 2.0
```

with

```
import QtQuick 2.13
```

in project.

Is use replace tool the best way?

Comment: You are doing it write. You can use regular expression search to be safe.

Comment: find ./src/ -type f -exec sed -i 's#import QtQuick 2.0#import QtQuick 2.13#g' {} +